# Calculate average of duplicates in a javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapreduce, aggregate

I have an array of objects:

```
[
{"market": "Qacha's nek","commodity": 55,"price": "90","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Mohales Hoek","commodity": 55,"price": "75","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Mafeteng","commodity": 55,"price": "75","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Maseru","commodity": 55,"price": "69","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Butha-Buthe","commodity": 55,"price": "66","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Leribe","commodity": 55,"price": "64","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Butha-Buthe","commodity": 55,"price": "65","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Thaba-Tseka","commodity": 55,"price": "82","month": "04","year": "2017"},
{"market": "Thaba-Tseka","commodity": 55,"price": "81","month": "04","year": "2017"},
{"market": "Maseru",    "commodity": 55,"price": "74,99","month": "04","year": "2017"}
]
```

**I'm trying to aggregate duplicates by price average**.

So the keys to identifying duplicated rows are all the properties except **price**, that must be aggregated by average.

In the data above, for example, line 5 and 7:

```
5) "market": "Butha-Buthe","commodity": 55,"price": "66","month": "04","year": "2017"
7) "market": "Butha-Buthe","commodity": 55,"price": "65","month": "04","year": "2017"
```

are duplicates and I want to merge them and make the average of their price value.

I was trying to use the **reduce** function, but I can't figure out how to identify duplicated values, especially if they are not sorted.

I post the code, but it's useless as I can't understand how to identify duplicates with reduce:

```js
var data = [
{"market": "Qacha's nek","commodity": 55,"price": "90","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Mohales Hoek","commodity": 55,"price": "75","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Mafeteng","commodity": 55,"price": "75","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Maseru","commodity": 55,"price": "69","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Butha-Buthe","commodity": 55,"price": "66","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Leribe","commodity": 55,"price": "64","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Butha-Buthe","commodity": 55,"price": "65","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Thaba-Tseka","commodity": 55,"price": "82","month": "04","year": "2017"},
{"market": "Thaba-Tseka","commodity": 55,"price": "81","month": "04","year": "2017"},
{"market": "Maseru","commodity": 55,"price": "74,99","month": "04","year": "2017"}
];

var avg = data.reduce(function(result, current) {
   console.log(result,current);
      if(!result){
       result=current;
      }
      else {
       if(result.market==current.market){
         console.log(current.market);
        }
      }
});
```

Here a jsfiddle where I was trying to understand how the reduce function works:
https://jsfiddle.net/brainsengineering/7tmdx0kg/7/

Comment: All code directly here please ...

Comment: Hi! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can make your MCVE runnable using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Why is `price` a string?

Comment: @JonasWilms unfortunately, the backend service returned this way... I know it shouldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a combined key for the wanted properties and replace the `price` format to a numerical parsable format.

```js
var data = [{ market: "Qacha's nek", commodity: 55, price: "90", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Mohales Hoek", commodity: 55, price: "75", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Mafeteng", commodity: 55, price: "75", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Maseru", commodity: 55, price: "69", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Butha-Buthe", commodity: 55, price: "66", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Leribe", commodity: 55, price: "64", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Butha-Buthe", commodity: 55, price: "65", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Thaba-Tseka", commodity: 55, price: "82", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Thaba-Tseka", commodity: 55, price: "81", month: "04", year: "2017" }, { market: "Maseru", commodity: 55, price: "74,99", month: "04", year: "2017" }],
    keys = ['market', 'commodity', 'month', 'year'],
    count = {},
    result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var key = keys.map(function (k) { return o[k]; }).join('|');
        if (!count[key]) {
            count[key] = { sum: +o.price.replace(',', '.'), data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o)) };
            count[key].data.count = 1;
            r.push(count[key].data);
        } else {
            count[key].sum += +o.price.replace(',', '.');
            count[key].data.price = (count[key].sum / ++count[key].data.count).toString();
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thought of using a hashtable for counts, but I couldn't find a way without transforming the object at least two times, this combined object/array is just very elegant :)

Comment: @nina always the best on map and reduce! This solution is really the best as I can define also the keys. And would it possible to add a new property to the object for keeping track of the count (how many elements have been aggregated)?

Comment: @Giox, now with `count` in the result set.

Comment: This code certainly does the job but I wouldn't want to maintain it for sure. Not sure OP will even understand how it actually works...

Comment: @mkhanoyan you're right, it's difficult, I'm trying to understand it line by line, but all the map&reduce algorythm are difficult to understand, at least for me.

Comment: There is a trick that @NinaScholz is using there. After pushing the data to the result array (in the `r.push(count...` line), she relies on the fact that javascript is a "pass by reference" language.
You need to understand that when she updates the price in `count` object (last line of the else block) she is also updating the result array.

I think it would benefit you to start from scratch and try to solve the problem without using `reduce` first.

Comment: @mkhanoyan, the trick is just to know the language features and how do apply them. but you are right. the hash tabel contains the reference `data` to the result set `r`. any update of `data` property i reflected in the result set, because of the same object reference.

Answer (score 2):

Group prices together for each item by adding them to an array in your `reduce` call. You can keep track of which items are duplicated in the same function. Then use loop over the duplicate items to compute the averages.

Note I had to change your price `74,99` to `74.99` to parse more easily. You'll probably want some sort of localization/globalization library if this is critical in your use case.

```js
var data = [
{"market": "Qacha's nek","commodity": 55,"price": "90","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Mohales Hoek","commodity": 55,"price": "75","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Mafeteng","commodity": 55,"price": "75","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Maseru","commodity": 55,"price": "69","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Butha-Buthe","commodity": 55,"price": "66","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Leribe","commodity": 55,"price": "64","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Butha-Buthe","commodity": 55,"price": "65","month": "04","year": "2017"}, 
{"market": "Thaba-Tseka","commodity": 55,"price": "82","month": "04","year": "2017"},
{"market": "Thaba-Tseka","commodity": 55,"price": "81","month": "04","year": "2017"},
{"market": "Maseru","commodity": 55,"price": "74.99","month": "04","year": "2017"}
];

function parsePrice(str) {
  // TODO: localization
  return +str;
}

function formatPrice(num) {
  return num.toFixed(2);
}

function getHashKey(item) {
  return JSON.stringify([item.market, item.commodity, item.month, item.year]);
}

var duplicatedItems = {};
var prices = data.reduce(function(result, current) {
  var key = getHashKey(current);
  if (key in result) {
    result[key].push(parsePrice(current.price));
    duplicatedItems[key] = current;
  } else {
    result[key] = [parsePrice(current.price)];
  }
  return result;
}, {});
var avg = Object.keys(duplicatedItems).map(function(key) {
  var item = duplicatedItems[key];
  var avgPrice = prices[key].reduce(function(acc, price) { return acc + price; }, 0) / prices[key].length;
  return {
    market: item.market,
    commodity: item.commodity,
    price: formatPrice(avgPrice),
    month: item.month,
    year: item.year
  };
});

console.log(avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the values into a new array and merge if it already exists:

```
 const result = [];

 outer: for(const {  market, commodity,  price, month, year } of input) {
    for(const other of result) {
       if(market === other.market && commodity === other.commodity && month === other.month && year === other.year) {
         other.prices.push(+price);

         continue outer;
       }
    }
    result.push({ market, commodity, prices: [+price], month, year });
 }

 for(const group of result)
   group.price = group.prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / group.prices.length;
```

Comment: is it compatible with IE11?

Comment: @giox no, it isn't. Transpile it if needed.